# How should I understand "The user program never sees the real physical addresses"?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I'm reading *Operating System Concepts* by Avi Silberschatz, in chapter 8 Main Memroy, it goes like:

> The user program never sees the real physical addresses. The program can create a pointer to location 346, store it in memory, manipulate it, and compare it
>   with other addresses—all as the number 346. Only when it is used as a memory
>   address (in an indirect load or store, perhaps) is it relocated relative to the base register.

and

> The final location of
>   a referenced memory address is not determined until the reference is made.

In my understanding, when the pointer storing lacation 346 is used as a memory address, it will be relocated to a physical address. What does the author mean that the user program never see the real physical addresses here?

Comment: The OS manages the memory. This is an abstraction. i.e. your program doesn't have to manage memory directly, it's just ask the OS "can you store this somewhere please" and it decides where it's stored, etc.

Comment: @Liam In a program that the data stored in a pointer need to be fetched and stored in another variable, the program must get the pointer's physical address and then access it to get the data in that physical address, how can we say that the program never sees the real physical address?

Comment: This does depend on what you want a "program" to be (for example assembler would manage memory more directly than (say) Java). But ultimately the physical location of the memory is typically managed by the OS. It writes bytes x to location y. The "program" would simply say can I have those bytes I asked you to keep in memory, The OS would then look up the address and return the bytes. This also allows the OS to manage conflicting memory demands from various programs simultaneously, etc.

Comment: @Liam So it's equivalent to say that only in kernel mode can physical address be seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm reading Operating System Concepts by Avi Silberschatz, in chapter 8 Main Memroy, it goes like:

That's your first problem. Find another book.

At the high level, most processors these days use logical address translation. Each process sees a linear range of addresses. This range of addresses is divided into pages normally around of 512B to 1MB (some go up to a GB). In most processors the size of a page is fixed but in others its can be variable. For this discussion I will stick to a fixed page size.

Physical memory is divided into PAGE FRAMES of the same size as the PAGE on the system.

When a process accesses an address, the processor divides the address into a page number and an offset into that page (since page tables sizes are powers of two, this is just bit extractions). The processor then translates the page into a page frame.

This translation is done using page tables. The operating system has to maintain, for each process, page tables that define the mapping between pages and page frames. At least one range of addresses will have the same mapping for all processes. For most pages, the mapping tends to be unique. AND, many pages will have no mapping at all. Accessing pages without a mapping will causes a memory fault of some kind.

This translation is done entirely behind the scenes by the operating system and the processor. Most processes totally ignore page translation. On most systems, a process cannot determine which physical page frames it uses.

During execution, the mapping of pages to page frames can change.

That is why

> The user program never sees the real physical addresses.

The rest of the gibberish in your example apparently is taking about pointers. In most processors (ignoring many Kludges by Intel), addresses are just integers.

Let's us say that I think I have an array of four-byte integers at address 0x1234 and I want to get read the one at number 5 (assuming indices start at zero). In a simple assembly language I could do something like

```
 MOVE #0x1234, R0 ; R0 points to the start of the array
 MOVE #5, R1  
 MUL #4, R1  ; R1 is the offset to the 5th element of the array.
 ADD R1, R0  ; R0 now points to the 5th element.
```

At this point this code has not touched memory.

> The final location of a referenced memory address is not determined until the reference is made.

Then if I do

```
MOV (R0), R1
```

This will move the value stored in the location specified by R0 into R1 (which is 0x1234 + 5 * 4). At that point, the logical memory translation kicks in and the processor has to find the page frame that is mapped to the address (0x1234 + 5 * 4).

When the operations are done using registers, no memory is involved, so there is no memory translation. This is one of several reasons why register operations are much faster than memory operations.

Comment: The book is obviously confusing given the number of questions posted to this board including quotes from it that make the simple complex.

Comment: What do you mean "At least one range of addresses will have the same mapping for all processes." ? I'm a little bit confused here.

Comment: Another question is that in your answer, it is the operating system who finishes the translation from logical address to physical address, but by @mightyWOZ , it's the MMU who does the job, so what's the truth here? Does MMU work together with operating system to decide the corresponding physical address?

Comment: In order for the OS to function, the addresses it uses must be the same for all processes. The range of system address is the same for all processes and the logical addresses for system pages map to the same page frame in all processes. In addition, it is possible for multiple processes to map to the same physical location as part of application program. In that case,the logical addresses usually are not the same among the variousprocesses.

Comment: In re the second question, the operating system defines the logical to physical mapping. The MMU reads the tables defined by the operating system to do the actual translation. I guess you could say the OS and MMU. A better way to to say it is that the OS programs (or directs) the MMU how to translate the addresses. It is more of master/slave thing than cooperative.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the author mean that the user program never see the real
>   physical addresses here?

**Short answer:** - your program uses what is called as logical addresses. To map these logical addresses to physical addresses there is something called MMU. You cannot directly use physical addresses (unless you are some low level beast).

**Long answer: -**

Terminology

Physical address: - actual addresses that memory unit sees.

Logical address: - addresses that a program sees but they cannot be used directly to access memory, instead a translation must be performed to change them to the actual addresses. You may ask why we need these logical addresses. (Read on)

Let’s say you have a computer with 4 GiB of memory and you being a programmer don’t feel the need of an OS instead your write your programs as needs arise. Every program you write can use entire 4GiB of memory and they directly use physical addresses (if you say read x, you are reading x location directly from memory). Everything was going fine until one day your friend comes along (who doesn’t have a computer) and says your program don’t need entire 4 GiB, so could you please let me run my program alongside yours. You agree and load his program and all of sudden everything just crashes.

**What happened?**

Well as both of your programs can see the physical addresses, they used same physical address to store some of their data which lead to data corruption and your system crashed. To be specific both of your programs said something like write to x and because x is physical address they both effectively wrote to same physical location.

**How to fix it?**

let's introduce a middle man and call him MMU. MMU maps your process’s logical address space to physical address space and also makes sure that logical address of your friend’s program doesn’t get mapped to same physical region. So now when you say write to location x, MMU takes x and translates it to some physical address (you don’t know what is this physical address), on the same time if your friend’s program says write to location x, MMU maps it to some other physical address. Your programs still see an address space equal to 4Gib but now addresses used by your programs are not physical instead they are called logical. The process of memory access is still the same from your perspective. You still say read from x. but now MMU maps this x to some physical location which is in your physical address space and doesn’t conflict with your friend’s address space.

[image]

this is most basic example of a MMU. This MMU stores relocation address of every process. for our example lets say your program have a relocation address of 0 and your friends program has a relocation address 2000. so when you say write to 100, it gets translated to write to (0+100). but in case of your friend it translated to write to (2000+100).

by using MMU and by not letting your programs see the physical memory, you have successfully introduced the security in your system.(no two processes can use same physical location and hence cant corrupt each other's data).